# AWS ESM TumblingWindowInSeconds vs MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

Looking at the ESM options here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-parallelizationfactor

And I'm seeing two properties that look the same:

**MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds**

(Streams and Amazon SQS standard queues) The maximum amount of time, in seconds, that Lambda spends gathering records before invoking the function.

**TumblingWindowInSeconds**

(Streams only) The duration in seconds of a processing window. The range is between 1 second up to 900 seconds.

---

I am setting up a DDB Stream ESM to Lambda and am unsure what the difference is between these two.

What is the difference between **MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds** and **TumblingWindowInSeconds**?